# Making a turtle choices script, asks for colour and shape, my turtle commands are not working in my if statement

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
Drawing = input('''Select a drawing:
1. Square
2. Triangle
3. Star
''')

Colour = input("What colour would you like (red/green/blue)? ")

import turtle

if Drawing == 1:

    import turtle
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(150)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.color("{Colour}")
    turtle.done()
```

Comment: `input` gives you a string, not an integer.

Comment: You should convert your `Drawing` variable into int type using expression `Drawing = int(Drawing)`

Answer (score 1):

Inputs give a string, not an integer, so the change would be simple. Make the 1 in your if statement a string by putting quote marks around it. `if Drawing == "1"`.